Bumping up questions
I've noticed that sometimes posters bump their own questions up by making tiny mods to the question. Is there a way to stop this from happening, eg only admin / community can place questions at the front of the queue again and / or if there is a new answer?

I think this is somewhat acceptable behaviour. Improvements by editing are welcome and the platform is programmed so that any change will cause the question to bubble up. However, if you feel that a series of edits are maybe a bit too minor minor and made tactically, please feel free to flag those for moderator attention.
